# Problem calling out a boolean expression method

Tags: java

I recently picked up programming and was practicing doing some exercises, in this exercise I was required to use create a method(arr, ascendnig) that sorts any given array either by ascending or descending, depending on the the boolean expression of ascending (true = asc).

Below is the code that I wrote with some comments to convey what I was trying to do, I met several problems when executing (not by the compiler, the code didn't do what I wanted it to do)

1. When using a single " = " sign, the code only compiled the true portion of the method.
2. I tried using "==" instead, and it did compile the false portion, HOWEVER when calling out the method it only did a normal sort instead of going through the rest of the code. To check if my for loop worked as intended and that the values did get transferred to the arr[] I did a println command and the values were correct, however when calling out the method it was as it didn't care about this portion of the code.

Any help so I can understand the logic and fix my code will be appreciated!

```
public static void sort(double[] arr, boolean ascending) {
     
     
    if (ascending = true) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);


    }
     
    else if (ascending = false ) {
        
        int temp = arr.length;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        
        //Sort the ascended sorted array into a new array by swapping their index values
    
        double [] tempArr = new double[arr.length];
        
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            tempArr[i] = arr[temp-1];
            temp--;


        }
        
        // Give the temporary descending array values back to the method variable
        
        arr = tempArr;
        System.out.println("expression is false4 " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double[] arr2 = {9,2,5};
    System.out.println("The array before sorting is " + Arrays.toString(arr2));
    sort(arr2, 10<4);
    System.out.println("The array after sorting is " + Arrays.toString(arr2) );
```

Comment: `arr = tempArr;` does not change the array which was previous referenced in `arr`, so the array `arr2` from your `main()` method remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, = and == have different meanings.

= is assigment operator, while == is equality relationship for primitive types and object's references.

In your case, you don't need both of them, since `if` operator takes any expression that can be evaluated to `boolean` type.

So, we can rewrite

```
    if (ascending = true) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);


    }
     
    else if (ascending = false ) {
```

with

```
    if (ascending) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
    } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

In both places you are checking ascending, you have single =.
Single = is used for assignment, doubble == is used for comparison.

In this case you are setting the variable ascending to be true in your first if-statement:

```
if (ascending = true) {
```

The assignment itself evaluates to true so the that branch is executed.

Then in the else you do the same with false, but this of course evaluates to false so that branch is skipped:

```
else if (ascending = false ) {
```

You can change both to == or, skip the == completely since the variable is already a boolean and do this:

```
if (ascending) {
    //....
} else {
   //....
```